# Write and read a list from file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

This is a slightly weird request but I am looking for a way to write a list to file and then read it back some other time.

I have no way to remake the lists so that they are correctly formed/formatted as the example below shows.

My lists have data like the following:

```
test
data
here
this
is one
group :)

test
data
here
this
is another
group :)
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If you don't need it to be human-readable/editable, the easiest solution is to just use `pickle`.

To write:

```
with open(the_filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_list, f)
```

To read:

```
with open(the_filename, 'rb') as f:
    my_list = pickle.load(f)
```

---

If you *do* need them to be human-readable, we need more information.

If `my_list` is guaranteed to be a list of strings with no embedded newlines, just write them one per line:

```
with open(the_filename, 'w') as f:
    for s in my_list:
        f.write(s + '\n')

with open(the_filename, 'r') as f:
    my_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

---

If they're Unicode strings rather than byte strings, you'll want to `encode` them. (Or, worse, if they're byte strings, but not necessarily in the same encoding as your system default.)

If they might have newlines, or non-printable characters, etc., you can use escaping or quoting. Python has a variety of different kinds of escaping built into the stdlib.

Let's use `unicode-escape` here to solve both of the above problems at once:

```
with open(the_filename, 'w') as f:
    for s in my_list:
        f.write((s + u'\n').encode('unicode-escape'))

with open(the_filename, 'r') as f:
    my_list = [line.decode('unicode-escape').rstrip(u'\n') for line in f]
```

---

You can also use the 3.x-style solution in 2.x, with either the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module or the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) module:*

```
import io

with io.open(the_filename, 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    f.writelines(line + u'\n' for line in my_list)

with open(the_filename, 'r') as f:
    my_list = [line.rstrip(u'\n') for line in f]
```

<sub>* TOOWTDI, so which is the one obvious way? It depends… For the short version: if you need to work with Python versions before 2.6, use `codecs`; if not, use `io`.</sub>

Comment: I like the pickle library, that's pretty sweet and works perfectly. I've already implemented it and it seems to be working okay.

Thank you, I'll mark you as a green tick as soon as it lets me.

Comment: unicode-escape... I had to open it as 'wb' because of TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Comment: @Pan.student: You're using Python 3.x, right? In Python 2, which is what this question was asking about, `str` and `bytes` are the same type, and the difference between binary files and text files is just newline translation. In Python 3, `str` and `unicode` are the same type, and the difference between binary files and text files is that text files automatically encode and decode for you. (You can get 3.x-like behavior if 2.x if you're careful, including 3.x-style text files with `io.open`, but the asker wasn't doing that.)

Comment: @Pan.student: In 3.x, you're probably better off with using `open(the_filename, 'w', encoding='unicode-escape')` and letting the file object take care of encoding it for you. (You can do the same in 2.x with either `io.open` or the `codecs` module, but I think explicit encoding makes it easier to see what's going on in 2.x, where the danger of mixing bytes and text is much higher.)

Comment: With the second option on Python 2.7, instead of multiple lines, it saves a single line with plaintext `\n` in between. Changing `f.write((s + u'\n').encode('unicode-escape'))` to `f.write(s.encode('unicode-escape') + u'\n')` fixes it.

Comment: @hugo: That's exactly what I meant by doing it manually. If you're writing pure-2.x code (as opposed to 2.x/3.x code) I think it's often clearer to call encode than to use the io module. Or, putting it another way, if you really want the io module, there's a good chance you want to write 3.x code with 2.x backward compat instead of 2.x code.

Comment: `with io.open(the_filename, 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as f:
    f.writelines(line + u'\n' for line in my_list)` is giving a list on a single line with \n in between

Comment: Removing the encoding part and the "u" fixes it so it becomes:
`with io.open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:  f.writelines(line + "\n" for line in lines)`

Answer (score 15):

As long as your file has consistent formatting (i.e. line-breaks), this is easy with just basic file IO and string operations:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'rU') as in_file:
    data = in_file.read().split('\n')
```

That will store your data file as a list of items, one per line. To then put it into a file, you would do the opposite:

```
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(data)) # This will create a string with all of the items in data separated by new-line characters
```

Hopefully that fits what you're looking for.

Comment: +1. If the `data` we are talking about isn't complex, IMHO it is better to roll your own parser like in this ans.

Answer (score 6):

Let's define a list first:

```py
lst=[1,2,3]
```

You can directly write your list to a file:

```py
f=open("filename.txt","w")
f.write(str(lst))
f.close()
```

To read your list from text file first you read the file and store in a variable:

```
f=open("filename.txt","r")
lst=f.read()
f.close()
```

The type of variable `lst` is of course string. You can convert this string into array using `eval` function.

```py
lst=eval(lst)
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks!