# How do I convert a list into a string for printing in an output txt file in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have tried using this in order to convert my list of sorted numbers into a string so I can print it to an output txt file.

```
    output_str = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list)
    print("This is the text (string) that will be written on the output file")
    print(output_str)
    text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(output_str)

    text_file.close()
```

For some reason, it creates an output file but it does not print what I want, it comes out blank.

I got `output_str = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list)`
from another thread, are there any alternatives? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it print the correct string on the print line above the write?

Comment: you shouldnt name your variable `list`, it's reserved keyword. Could you print its content by the way.

Comment: Your code works fine as long as there is something in the list. @ericrenouf had a great question. Care to answer it?

Answer (score 1):

you can just loop over the list and write to your file one character (number) at a time.

```
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
for num in list:
    text_file.write(str(num) + ' ')

text_file.close()
```

Comment: I'd use a "with open" as documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225287/python-2-7-write-and-read-a-list-from-file) and I would change the list name from list but this is the best answer I've seen so far.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams apologies - edited to add the space between numbers.

Comment: @JGreenwell you're right about the with open statement. I overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: This is no solution to the problem if OPs code doesn't work, this won't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Asking about an alternative to your code line `output_str = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list)`. You can use `map` to convert each number to str then use `join`

```
 output_str = ' '.join(map(str, list_))
```

I would suggest to rename your variable `list` to `list_` cause it's a reserved keyword

Comment: Why do you think a string conversion would help? OP mentioned nothing about an exception.

Comment: @tdelaney @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams he asked about alternatives to his code line `output_str = ' '.join(str(e) for e in list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable you're iterating over actually called `list`? Because there is a built-in function [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list) which could be giving you troubles. I ran a slight variation on your code:

```
>>> output_str = ' '.join(str(e) for e in [1,4,5,7,9])
>>> print("This is the text (string) that will be written on the output file")
This is the text (string) that will be written on the output file
>>> print(output_str)
1 4 5 7 9
>>> text_file = open("deleteme.txt", "w")
>>> text_file.write(output_str)
>>> text_file.close()
```

The file did contain what I would expect:

```
1 4 5 7 9
```

Comment: Using a variable named list has risks but won't cause any problems with OPs posted code.

Answer (score -1):

You can try  this code :

```
output_str = []
for e in list:
  output_str.append(str(e))
output = ''.join(output_str)
```

and then write in your file

Comment: Why do you believe that this is better than what the asker already has?

Comment: OP didn't mention any exceptions. This does nothing to fix the code.