# How to save and load a list in a txt file

Tags: python, list

I have a list of names
`list = ["Bob", "Fred", "George", "Garry"]` and I would like to be able to save it after changing it (like if I were to add another name to the list) and then load it again later. So far I save it by:

```
    text_file = open("/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/names.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(str(list))
    text_file.close()
    print("Your list has been saved!")
```

This saves the list as a string `['Bob', 'Fred', 'George', 'Garry']` so when I load it again I can't access it as a list.

```
testList=[]
with open("/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/names.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            testList.append(line)
        print(testList[0])
```

Output: `['Bob', 'Fred', 'George', 'Garry']`

I want it so I can `print(testList[0])` and get `Bob` after loading the list I saved earlier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write and read a list from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225287/write-and-read-a-list-from-file)

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can save each list item to a new line and then just recreate the list when reading.

Write to file:

```
# define list of places
places = ['Berlin', 'Cape Town', 'Sydney', 'Moscow']

with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in places:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```

Read from file:

```
# define an empty list
places = []

# open file and read the content in a list
with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        currentPlace = line[:-1]

        # add item to the list
        places.append(currentPlace)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save and read files in python (and not in external systems) you could have a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). It's a python module that stores a variable in a pickle file and makes it easy to reload the file and directly start working with it again!

Answer (score 0):

Txt documents are not able to hold list elements, but you can store the list in JSON as a JavaScript object. For information on how to do that, go here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp.
Another way to achieve this is to print out the names, one by one, into the txt document and then using the read function to read it and put it back into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Change your saving code to the following

```
text_file = open("/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/names.txt", "w")
    text_file.writelines(list)
    text_file.close()
    print("Your list has been saved!")
```

This will save each name on a new line. The **writelines** function will write each string in your list to a new line in your file. When you want to load it from a file, you can do it the way you are now which will work, or do the following.

```
testList=[]
with open("/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/names.txt") as f:
        testList = f.readlines()
```